# Trying to connect C# ASP.NET MVC app to a docker container running postgres and I keep getting "password authentication failed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, docker

I have an ASP.NET Identity app that uses a postgres server on the backend. I started the postgres server like this `docker run --name postgres-newtester -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgresNewtesterPW1 -d postgres`.

Then I went into the cli of the running docker container and ran the following commands:

```
psql postgres postgres  
CREATE DATABASE amaranth_tests;
CREATE USER amaranth_test_user WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'amaranth_test_userPW1';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE amaranth_tests TO amaranth_test_user;
\q
exit
```

Then I changed my connection string in `appsettings.Development.json` to:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "db": "Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=amaranth_tests;Username=amaranth_test_user;Password=amaranth_test_userPW1"
  }
```

I went to my C# MVC app and ran `dotnet restore`, then `dotnet ef database update`. I got the following error in my terminal:

```
password authentication failed for user "amaranth_test_user"
```

I'm assuming that this is because my connection string is giving the password for the postgres user but not for the actual docker container. When I switch `Password=amaranth_test_userPW1` to `Password=postgresNewtesterPW1` I get the same error. So it seems that I need to give both the docker container password and postgres password. How do I put both of these into the connection string? Or is there another way to do this?

P.S. One follow up question, is there an easier way to do all of this?

Comment: Look in the db server's log file to see if there is a more detailed error message.

Comment: If you're talking about the log panel for the postgres container in the docker desktop dashboard, it doesn't appear to be logging the activity

Comment: is this aspnet app running on docker or on your local environment?

Comment: The C# app is running locally. Only the postgres db is running in docker

Comment: the problem is that ef doesn't know which is the connection sting. Please, try running the command like this: dotnet ef database update --connection "connection string

Comment: I tired that, same exact error

Comment: I don't use 'docker desktop', just the command line, but it seems like a likely place.  If you are connecting to a different server than you intended, then of course the log will also be going to a different place.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem it's this: https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-postgresql/issues/112#issuecomment-579712540.

Basically Windows runs PostgreSQL server through localhost on port `5432` so it conflicts with the Docker container postgres which also runs on port `5432`. It runs great on my Mac but on my Windows computer it doesn't work. In the Github issue eddex says to turn off the Windows PostgreSQL service and it will work. He also details a few other options.